# Compiling a Clang plugin in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, clang

I've tried the basic example of clang plugins in Windows [PrintFunctionNames](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/examples/PrintFunctionNames/)
When I used the below command:

> cmake .

In it's folder, it gives an error stating that cmake_minimum_version is not specified and when I add that, I receive another error stating:

> Unknown CMake command "add_llvm_loadable_module".

Any approach that I tried to pass this one has resulted in another error that I could not fix. How should I create this plugin in **Windows** (not necessarily using Visual Studio)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CMakeLists.txt from the location you have posted is 'incomplete'. It is not meant to be used without parental CMakeLists.txt.

What you need to do is one of:

- compile whole clang from the [top dir](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/)
- add missing stuff to CMakeLists.txt you are using now

Comment: Thanks. I had run `make PrintFunctionNames` from top level (llvm-build) and it worked.